# How to one-click print in Access 2010

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I want to create a button on a form in Access 2010 that, when clicked, prints the current record/view of a form. I have tried various VBA scripts. Some print all records, others print partial parts of the form, but not the whole form.

If I hit Ctrl-P, then select "Selected Records", then click OK, it prints the current record/view of the form just fine.

What code can I put in the On Click event prodecure to do the same thing as Ctrl-P, "Selected Records", and "OK" without the user having to do all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I saved the form as a report, then I created a button on the form that has this for its code:

```
Dim strReportname As String
Dim strCriteria As String

strReportname = "ReportfrmClients"
strCriteria = "[ClientID] = " & Me!ClientID

DoCmd.OpenReport strReportname, acNormal, , strCriteria
```

That sends the report directly to the print queue without opening it. And it only sends one ClientID to the report, so the report only prints the one record.